# How to send double from client to server and back to client using I/O

Tags: java

I cannot use scanners or printwriters

I have a client, and a server.

i run the server and the output is,

```
Creating Server Socket 5095 . . . 
SUCCESS!!!
in while loop
Waiting for connection.
```

then i run the  client and the output is,

```
Creating Client Socket 
SUCCESS!!!
initializing variables
variables flushed
initializing input
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble(Unknown Source)
at Client.runClient(Client.java:38)
at Client.main(Client.java:51)
```

I would like to initialize some doubles in the client, and send them to the server, where they will be parsed and manipulated, with the result then being sent back to the client.

The client fails with an `EOFException` and the server fails with a `ClassCastException`

What Am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client {

static void pStr(String p) {
    System.out.println(p);
}

static void runClient() {

    Socket client;
    DataOutputStream output;
    DataInputStream input;

    try {
        pStr("Creating Client Socket ");
        client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5095);
        pStr("SUCCESS!!!");

        input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("initializing variables");
        double arg1 = 5;
        output.writeDouble(arg1);
        output.flush();

        double arg2 = 3;
        output.writeDouble(arg2);
        output.flush();

        System.out.println("variables flushed");

        System.out.println("initializing input");
        // error occurs at next line
        double ans = input.readDouble();
        System.out.println("input has been read");
        System.out.println(ans);

        input.close();
        output.close();
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 // this is second class file
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Client.runClient();
}
}
public class SimpleServer {

static void pStr(String p) {
    System.out.println(p);
}

static void runServer() {
    ServerSocket server;

    try {
        // Create a ServerSocket.
        pStr("Creating Server Socket " + 5095 + " . . . ");
        server = new ServerSocket(5095);
        pStr("SUCCESS!!!");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("in while loop");
            Socket connection;
            DataOutputStream output = null;
            DataInputStream input = null;

            pStr("Waiting for connection.");
            connection = server.accept();
            pStr("Done");

            System.out.println("entering try");

            try {
                // Get input and output streams.
                input = (DataInputStream) connection.getInputStream();
                output = (DataOutputStream) connection.getOutputStream();

                String ansStr;

                double arg1, arg2;
                try {
                    System.out.println("int try block");
                    arg1 = input.readDouble();
                    arg2 = input.readDouble();

                    ansStr = "" + arg1 + "," + arg2;
                    System.out.println(ansStr);

                    output.writeDouble(arg1);
                    output.writeDouble(arg2);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ansStr = e.getMessage();
                }
                output.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                pStr("Error in Protocol: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        pStr("Error making ServerSocket");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    runServer();
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I believe the client crashes when it attempts to write the double to the outputStream.

Comment: "crashes" is a very vague term, there must be an error thrown.

Comment: initial post updated

Comment: Your edit is still wrong. Your client fails with the `EOFException` that appears in the stack trace you posted. Your *server* fails with a `ClassCastException` in the stack trace you *didn't* post. Re your comment above, it is obvious from the stack trace that the client crashes with `EOFException` when it attempts to *read* from the *input* stream. You need to take a lot more notice of stack traces than you have so far.

Comment: Sigh. When are you going to post the missing `ClassCastException` stack trace?

Comment: what makes you assume that I even know what a stack trace is? I didnt post the ClassCastException stack trace because I did not see it. I am no longer able to produce the error but if you have the stacktrace feel free to post it in the original post.

Comment: What makes me 'assume' it is the fact that you managed to post one in your original question. The issue here is that you didn't post the complete output from the server. I've never run your code so I don't 'have' the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server code is crashing with a `ClassCastException` which you have unaccountably failed to mention. The connection is therefore being closed without any data being sent, hence the client-side exception.

You cannot get a `DataInputStream` or `DataOutputStream` from a socket just by casting. You have to use the same process you're using in the client.

Comment: i modified initial post to include the solution

Comment: @rickyjoepr You should **not** do that. It makes your question meaningless. I rolled it back. You should modify it to show the *real problem,* i.e. the `ClassCastException` you omitted from the server output.